# Запрос на объединение 3 таблиц

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте у мня есть 3 таблицы

```
1.Камеры : 
    id_1C, Name, id_vdr
2 Статистика : 
    id_vdr, status, дата, время
3 Вагоны : 
    id_1C , вагоны (кол-во), дата
```

Нужно из этих таблиц сделать запросом вывод данных
Дата, Name, вагоны (кол-во), и количество id_vdr за дату (count(id_vdr))

Проблема в том что во 2 таблице нет статусов всех камер за день, а только те что за день включались/выключались. А данные нужно между собой сопоставить, сколько включений было за день и сколько вагонов прошло через камеры. Нужно как-то вывести из статистики нули.
Мой запрос работает некорректно, в зависимости от даты может вывести 0 а может нет

```
SElect   [Вагоны].[Date]
         [Камеры].[Name]
         ,count ([Статистика].[id_vdr])
         ,[План_камеры_1С].[Vagons]
         FROM [Камеры], [Статистика], [Вагоны] 
  where ([Статистика].[id_vdr] = [Камеры].[id_vdr] or [Статистика].[id_vdr] is null)
        and [Камеры].[id_1C]= [Вагоны].[Id_1C] 
        and [Статистика].[Дата]= [Вагоны].[Date]
        and [Вагоны].[Date] = '20220604' 
GROUP BY [Вагоны].[Date], [Вагоны].[Vagons],[Камеры].[Name]
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

подскажите ошибку?

Comment: Как Вы получаете данные с Вагонов, если в `FROM` их нет. Два раза Камеры

Comment: я тут ошиблась.

Comment: В смысле тут ошиблась при копировании а в sql все верно.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру `CTEATE TABLE` и `INSERT INTO`, а также уточните версию SQL. + Примерный результат

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.6251.0  - версия SQL

Comment: 2022-06-04 00:00:00.000  1/10 Ц 1 360
2022-06-04 00:00:00.000  1/24 СТР 0 0
2022-06-04 00:00:00.000  1/26 СТР 742 280

Comment: не знаю как тут вставить картинку

Comment: Нажмите "Править" под вопросом и добавьте то, что просил выше

Comment: пробывали `JOIN`?

Comment: да пробовала, результат тот же

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что `id_vdr` - это количество, а не какой-нибудь идентификатор? Лучше бы конечно чтобы вы таблицы отправили как @MaxDown ранее говорил с заполненными данными иначе никто не будет разбираться с вашим вопросом.